# OnClickMethod custom adapter and access to textView

Tags: java, android

I have custom adapter for my listview (generated via model class, gson and asynctask).

I have also specyfic buttons on it for set alarm/wake up/share, etc.

This is my onItemClickMethod on Fragment and post execute of AsyncTask:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(final List<Model> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result != null) {
            adapter = new Adaptor(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, result);
            search_list.setAdapter(adapter);

            search_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Model modelList = result.get(position);
                    if(!mRadioManager.isPlaying()) {

                        mRadioManager.connect();
                        mRadioManager.startRadio(modelList.getRadio_url());
                        TextView title = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.title);
                        title.setText(modelList.getRadio_name());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mRadioManager.stopRadio();
                    }



                }
            });
```

How to access to specyfic Button? When I generate onClickListeners in Adapter for each element, they override my onItemClickListener. Ok, they are working but...

How to update TextView in this fragment from Adapter? I cannot access to TextView on Fragment using my Adapter.

[image]

Comment: So you would like to update a Textview that is already a part of your Listview?

Comment: TextView is outside my ListView, it's on layout bottom to ListView. 
When I click item on ListView, it should write clicked item in this TextView. Text is from DataModel. So I have Handler>rootView for ListView and additional TextView outside ListView

Comment: Is this `textview` not in the same class as the `onClickListener`?

Comment: Yes, not the same, it's element of fragment, so I cannot access it from Adapter to update. Adapter is rootView for listView elements (R.layout.list_item). 
When I am trying to access Fragment in Adapter, I have only  instantiate method.

Comment: problem solved, I used abstract class

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get what you mean. 
You can put your fragments view in your adapter constructor. 
Then, in your adapter make a global variable called fragmentView and assign the value from your constructor to it.

Now you can access your fragment view!

Comment: I added picture what I want to do.
Handler generates list of radio stations from json (gson, model, etc.)
When I click on radio station, it should update TextView on player. It's outside rootView from handler.

Comment: I'm not sure how you code is built. But it's the same answer, you just need to pass your fragments parent view (or even the text view itself) to wherever you need it.